# Wordpress Ajax pagination returning 0 after second time

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am attempting to paginate my posts with an ajax.

I set an attribute "data-page" to the page link and extract it with jQuery to pass it with Ajax.

The first time a click on the link everything works fine but then if I click on a different link the ajax call returns 0.

Here's my code in my functions.php:

```
    wp_register_script('load_post_ajax', get_template_directory_uri() .    '/includes/ajax/load_post_ajax.js',array( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    $php_array = array( 'admin_ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'load_post_ajax', 'php_array', $php_array );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'load_post_ajax' );
```

/*
 * PAGINATION
 */

```
function hs_pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{
$showitems = ($range * 2)+1;

if(isset($_POST['paged'])){
    $paged = $_POST['paged'];
}else{
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );
}

if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

if($pages == '')
{
    global $wp_query;
    $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$pages)
    {
        $pages = 1;
    }
}
if(1 != $pages)
{
    echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages." </span>";
    if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."' data-page=1>&laquo; First</a>";
    if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

    for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
    {
        if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
        {
            echo ($paged == $i)? "<a href=\"#\" class=\"current\" data-page=$i>".$i."</a>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\" data-page=$i>".$i."</a>";
        }
    }

    if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\" data-page=$paged + 1>Next &rsaquo;</a>";
    if ($paged < $pages-1 && $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."' data-page=$pages>Last &raquo;</a>";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

}

/*
 * AJAX POSTS LOADER
 */

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_post_ajax', 'load_post_ajax_init' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_post_ajax', 'load_post_ajax_init' );
function load_post_ajax_init() {
    $total_posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
    if($_POST['paged']){
       $paged = $_POST['paged'];
    }else{
       $paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );
    }

    $args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => $total_posts_per_page,
       'paged' => $paged,
       'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    $posts = query_posts($args);

if($posts){
    $count =0;
    foreach($posts as $post){
        ?>
        <article class="post">
            <?php
            if($paged < 2){
                if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ){
                    the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'big',array('class'=>'img-responsive center-block'));
                }else{
                    echo "no thumb";
                }
            }else{
                echo "not first post";
            }
            ?>
            <p class="post_info hs_color"><?php echo $post->post_title . " Posted on: " . $post->post_date . " Author: ". get_the_author_meta( 'display_name',$post->post_author );?></p>
            <p><?php echo $post->post_content;?></p>
            <div class="post_link clearfix">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID);?>">
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase text-center">Read more</h6>
                    <div class="hs_square hs_square_right hs_bg"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php
        $count++;
    }
}else {
    echo "no posts found";
}

//PAGINATION
hs_pagination();
//PAGINATION
```

}

/*
*AJAx CALL
*/

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

 $('#post-section .container .pagination a').on('click',function(e){
    /** Prevent Default Behaviour */
    e.preventDefault();

    var page = $(this).attr('data-page');

    /** Ajax Call */
    $.ajax({

        cache: false,
        timeout: 8000,
        url: php_array.admin_ajax,
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
            action:'load_post_ajax',
            paged:page,
        }),

        beforeSend: function() {
        },

        success: function( data,response ){
            $( '#post-section .container' ).addClass('animated FadeIn');
            $( '#post-section .container' ).html( data);
        },

        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log( 'The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown );
        },

    });


});
```

});